# Can't execute shell commands from gnuplot

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I'm trying to execute some commands from inside gnuplot, but I'm getting error.
As far as I understand I should use "!" before command.
Here is my script:

```
echo "
set terminal dumb 
!OUT=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo $PID | grep TOTAL )
!OUT=$(echo $OUT | sed -r 's/ +/ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
!echo $OUT >> adbmon.log
plot  'adbmon.log' using 1:6 title 'Free'
" > sample.gp && gnuplot sample.gp
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It would help if you show the error. I have no clue what you are actually trying here, seems so much more complicated than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every `!` a new shell is spawned, so that the variable `$OUT` is not available in the second call. You can also plot everything on-the-fly as follows:

```
gnuplot -persist -e "set terminal dumb; plot '< adb shell dumpsys meminfo $PID | grep TOTAL | sed -r ''s/ +/ /g'' | cut -d '' '' -f 2-' using 1:6"
```

Comment: In this case I didn't escape $ so command was completely useless.

Comment: And if you escape the `$` it works? Would surprise me.

Comment: I completely remade structure of this code, writing data to adbmon.log in different process. But thank you for your help I will keep in mind next time I use gnuplot